# How to convert complex filename into HTML link?

Tags: php, html

I have a directory with PDF files that I need to create an index for. It is a PHP page with a list of links:

```
<A HREF="path to file">filename</A>
```

The filenames can be complicated:

```
LVD 2-1133 - Ändring av dumpningslina (1984-11-20).pdf
```

What is the correct way to link to this file on a Linux/Apache server?

Is there a PHP function to do this conversion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [rawurlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php) to convert a string according to the RFC 1738 spec.
This function replaces all non-alphanumeric characters by their associated code.

The difference with [urlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) is that spaces are encoded as plus signs.

You'll probably want to use the last one.

This technique is called Percent or URL encoding. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Url_encoding) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

The urlencode() function will convert spaces into plus signs (+), so it won't work. The rawurlencode does the trick. Thanks.

Be sure to convert each part of the path separately, otherwise path/file will be converted into path%2Ffile. (which was what I missed)

Answer (score 0):

[urlencode()](http://se.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) should probably do what you want.

**Edit**: urlencode() works fine on swedish characters.

```
    <?php
        echo urlencode("åäö");   
    ?>
```

converts to:

```
    %E5%E4%F6
```

Answer (score 0):

[URL encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Url_encoding). I think it's `urlencode()` in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

[rawurlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php) will encode "exotic" characters in a URL.